# Uninstall Software Remote Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to uninstall a software on a remote computer by IP. I know the software is installed on the computer by the script keeps returning Software not found. I looked in the registry to see if the name was different from what was in control panel and the name matches unsure what I'm doing wrong

```
$computerName = "***,***,***"
$softwareName = "Epic Satellite"

$credential = Get-Credential

$software = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $computerName -Credential $credential | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $softwareName }

if ($software) {
    $software.Uninstall()
    Write-Host "Software '$softwareName' uninstalled successfully from '$computerName'."
} else {
    Write-Host "Software '$softwareName' not found on '$computerName'."
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is dcom on the remote computer working?  I would do it in remote powershell with uninstall-package.

Comment: I'm sill very new to PowerShell. I did look at dcom and it does look like its enabled but unsure how I would do a remote PowerShell session. I want to script this because we have multiple computers where i need to uninstall the software. The script works for another software i tested it on but it does not work on the software mentioned in the original post